# How could i get the date by the day of week in oracle 11g PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, dayofweek

How can i find what date will be in the next MONDAY if i have a current date(sysdate) and a current day of week?

p.s please tell me how to get date by day of week NOT day of week by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [next_day](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions106.htm#sthref1271) function:

```
select next_day(sysdate, 'MONDAY') from dual;
```

In case the national settings are not English we can have Oracle generate the localized translation of "Monday" and use it like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format="YYYY-MM-DD";

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language=italian;

Session altered.

SQL> declare
  2     v_monday constant varchar2(100) := to_char(to_date('2013-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'day');
  3  begin
  4     dbms_output.put_line('v_monday = ' || v_monday);
  5     dbms_output.put_line('next monday will be ' || next_day(sysdate, v_monday));
  6  end;
  7  /
v_monday = lunedi
next monday will be 2013-09-30

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language=spanish;

Session altered.

SQL> declare
  2     v_monday constant varchar2(100) := to_char(to_date('2013-09-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'day');
  3  begin
  4     dbms_output.put_line('v_monday = ' || v_monday);
  5     dbms_output.put_line('next monday will be ' || next_day(sysdate, v_monday));
  6  end;
  7  /
v_monday = lunes
next monday will be 2013-09-30

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: +1 - never knew this existed. However, it would fail when the session language isn't English.

Comment: @HAL9000: I have expanded my previous answer

Comment: it didn't fails if you use numbers instead of day of week names: select next_day(sysdate, 1) from dual;

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want to force giving current day and current date. Else you can make it more simpler with only date or with only month day.

```
WITH DATASET
    AS (SELECT
             'MON' AS CURRENT_DAY,
             '2013-06-26' AS CURENT_DATE
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      CASE
          WHEN CURRENT_DAY = 'MON'
          THEN
              TO_DATE ( CURENT_DATE,
                      'yyyy-mm-dd' )
              + INTERVAL '7' DAY
          WHEN CURRENT_DAY = 'TUE'
          THEN
              TO_DATE ( CURENT_DATE,
                      'yyyy-mm-dd' )
              + INTERVAL '6' DAY
          WHEN CURRENT_DAY = 'WED'
          THEN
              TO_DATE ( CURENT_DATE,
                      'yyyy-mm-dd' )
              + INTERVAL '5' DAY
          WHEN CURRENT_DAY = 'THU'
          THEN
              TO_DATE ( CURENT_DATE,
                      'yyyy-mm-dd' )
              + INTERVAL '4' DAY
          WHEN CURRENT_DAY = 'FRI'
          THEN
              TO_DATE ( CURENT_DATE,
                      'yyyy-mm-dd' )
              + INTERVAL '3' DAY
          WHEN CURRENT_DAY = 'SAT'
          THEN
              TO_DATE ( CURENT_DATE,
                      'yyyy-mm-dd' )
              + INTERVAL '2' DAY
          WHEN CURRENT_DAY = 'SUN'
          THEN
              TO_DATE ( CURENT_DATE,
                      'yyyy-mm-dd' )
              + INTERVAL '1' DAY
      END
          AS DATE_OF_NEXT_MON
FROM
      DATASET;
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether sunday is the first or last day of "your" week.

if your week starts with monday then use

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'iw') + 7 from dual;
```

if your week starts with sunday then use

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'w') + 8 from dual;
```